# How to drop IDs if the variables are populated for only a year?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a panel data, where some variables are missing. I intend to drop the IDs where the variables are populated for only one year (and 2, 3 so on), as that does not give me enough history to work with.

My example data is as follows:

```
id <- c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c', 'd')
time <- c(2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002, 2003,2003,2003,2003)
x <- c(1,2,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,7,8,9,NA,10,11,12,12)
y <- c(NA,2,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,7,8,9,NA,10,11,12,12)
z <- c(NA,2,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,7,8,9,NA,NA,11,12,NA)
w <- c(NA,2,NA,NA,4,5,NA,NA,7,8,9,NA,NA,11,12, 12)
mydata <- data.frame(id, time, x, y, z, w)
```

I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata.imp <- mydata %>% group_by(id,time) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

But this ends up giving me 0 observations where as I should have id a, b, c in my dataframe when I am dropping by one year condition (and a, b only with 2 year condition).

My expected dataframe is as follows for the one year condition:

```
id <- c('a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c')
time <- c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003)
x <- c(1,2,NA,4,5,NA,7,8,9,10,11,12)
y <- c(NA,2,NA,4,5,NA,7,8,9,10,11,12)
z <- c(NA,2,NA,4,5,NA,7,8,9,NA,11,12)
w <- c(NA,2,NA,4,5,NA,7,8,9,NA,11,12)
mydata.imp <- data.frame(id, time, x, y, z, w)
```

Any help at all is  very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say populated, does it mean all variables or at least one variable has to be populated for 2 years or more?

Comment: Hello @FelipeAlvarenga, I want at least one variable (say my priority is x) has to be populated for 2 years or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific example, the following works.

```
mydata %>% 
  mutate(handle = rowSums(.[, 3:6])) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(test = sum(!is.na(handle))) %>%
  filter(test > 0) %>%
  select(-test, - handle)

   id     time     x     y     z     w
   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a      2000     1    NA    NA    NA
 2 b      2000     2     2     2     2
 3 c      2000    NA    NA    NA    NA
 4 a      2001     4     4     4     4
 5 b      2001     5     5     5     5
 6 c      2001    NA    NA    NA    NA
 7 a      2002     7     7     7     7
 8 b      2002     8     8     8     8
 9 c      2002     9     9     9     9
10 a      2003    10    10    NA    NA
11 b      2003    11    11    11    11
12 c      2003    12    12    12    12
```

However, note that what I am doing is considering only `ids` that have ALL variables "populated" and than calculating the number of years each `id` appears with complete information.

If you want it to put a priority variable, i.e., check whether a single variable, or a subset of your variables, have at least 2 years of information, just change the `mutate(handle = rowSums(.[, 3:6]))` into `mutate(handle = rowSums(.[, "position of the variables"]))`

Comment: Hello, @Felipe Alvarenga. Thank you very much for this. The solution works with my actual data with 1 small modification. filter(test > 0) has to be filter(test >1). Otherwise it is great!